# "memory clobbered before allocated block" во время компиляции

Tags: c++, указатели

Доброго времени суток! Я пишу свой умный указатель и при компиляции возникает ошибка **memory clobbered before allocated block** Что она означает применительно к моему коду?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class control_block {
 public:
 T object;
 int count;
 control_block() {};
 control_block(T* p) {
   object = *p;
   count = 1;
 };
};

template<class T> 
class Myshared_ptr {
 private:
 T* pobj;
 control_block<T>* pblock;
 public:
 Myshared_ptr(): pobj(0), pblock() {
 };
 template<class Y>
 explicit Myshared_ptr(Y* p): pobj(p) {
  pblock = new control_block<T>;
  pblock->object = *p;
  pblock->count = 1;
 }
 Myshared_ptr(Myshared_ptr const& r): pobj(r.get()), pblock(r.get_block()) {
  *pblock.count++;  
 };

 ~Myshared_ptr() {
 if (pblock->count != 1) {
   delete pobj;
   pblock->count--;
 }
 else {
   delete pobj;
   delete pblock;
 };
};

Myshared_ptr& operator=(Myshared_ptr const& r) {
  pobj = r.get();
  pblock = r.get_block();
  *pblock.count++;  
};

template<class Y> 
Myshared_ptr& operator=(Myshared_ptr<Y> const& r) {
  pobj = r.get();
  pblock = r.get_block();
  *pblock.count++; 
}
void reset() {
  delete pobj;
  *pblock.count--;
};

T* get() const {
  return pobj;
};
control_block<T>* get_block() const {
  return pblock;
};
T& operator*() const {
  return *pobj;
};
T* operator->() const {
  return pobj;
};
long use_count() const {
  return pblock->count;
};
bool unique() const {
  return (pblock->count == 0);
};
};

template<class T, class U> 
bool operator==(Myshared_ptr<T> const& a, Myshared_ptr<U> const& b) {
  return a.get() == b.get();
}
template<class T, class U> 
bool operator!=(Myshared_ptr<T> const& a, Myshared_ptr<U> const& b) {
  return a.get() != b.get();
}
template<class E, class T, class Y>
basic_ostream<E, T>& operator<<(basic_ostream<E, T>& os, Myshared_ptr<Y> const& p) {
  os << p.get();
  return os;
}

int main() {
  int c = 5;
  int *b = &c;
  Myshared_ptr<int> a(b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: У меня Ваш код собрался, и упал уже при исполнении.



Для начала рекомендую задуматься о том, что не очень хорошо копировать объект внутрь smart_ptr (class control_block {
 public:
 T object;
). К smart_ptr обычно пожелание "на вот тебе указатель, позаботься, чтобы объект по нему был удалён, когда надо"

Comment: а разобраться, почему оно упало? тем более, что я уже написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ошибка в том, что Вы пытаетесь удалить объект, который создан на стеке. Так нельзя

исправленный main

```
int main() {
  int c = 5;
  int *b = new int (c);
  Myshared_ptr<int> a(b);
  return 0;
}
```

Ещё увидел две особенности в деструкторе

```
~Myshared_ptr() {
 if (pblock->count != 1) { // здесь лучше явно сравнивать больше-меньше
   delete pobj; // это удаление "инвариантно" по отношению к условию
   pblock->count--;
 }
 else {
   delete pobj;
   delete pblock;
 };
};
```

Я бы переписал как минимум так

```
~Myshared_ptr() {
 if (pblock->count > 1) { 
   pblock->count--;
 }
 else {
   delete pblock;
 };
 delete pobj;
};
```